# What is "Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities (No such file or directory)"

Tags: iphone, build

When I do an xcodebuild (headless commandline build) I get "Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities", but the build product is fine.

```
CompileXIB Resources/Main/InterfaceBuilder/XXX.xib
    cd /Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/XXX
    setenv IBC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 3.1.2
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/iPhoneBuildScript:/Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/iPhoneBuildScript:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/xxx/build/Release-iphoneos/XXX.app/XXX.nib /Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/XXX/Resources/Main/InterfaceBuilder/XXX.xib --sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk

Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix these warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have got the same problem with a project. I found the following site that explains more about what GSCapability is.

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/GSCapability

I was able to remove this message with the following steps;

1. Go to your application target, left mouse click "Get Info".
2. Go to the tab "Build".
3. Enter "other linker flags" in the search field.

The value contained '-framework Foundation -framework UIKit' in my case. Removing those linker flags resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanx. I'll try that out when I get back to work after my holiday.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error of "Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities". In my case I executed ibtool without the --sdk flag:

/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/xxx/build/Release-iphoneos/XXX.app/XXX.nib /Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/XXX/Resources/Main/InterfaceBuilder/XXX.xib

Adding the --sdk flag like you had it in the first place resolved my issue:

/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/xxx/build/Release-iphoneos/XXX.app/XXX.nib /Users/xxx/xcodeprojects/XXX/Resources/Main/InterfaceBuilder/XXX.xib --sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk

Thanks for the post

Answer (score 0):

After I recompiled my library that contains the xib, I got the error again. Then I re-ran ibtool and the error didn't show up again.

Very weird indeed.

In my case I have a static library, which contains a xib. The xib is compiled using ibtool to a nib (and it is here where the issue shows up first time only after a recompile of the static lib). The nib is then packaged in my ANE (Adobe native extension). Re-running ibtool for a second time doesn't give this issue again

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a command line build for the simulator with XCode4, it could be because you don't have i386 in the architectures list.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for me when I run unit testing targets from Xcode and the iOS Simulator is NOT running. If you launch (or quit and relaunch) the iOS Simulator, the errors stop appearing.