# Apple Mach-O Linker Error: Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, compiler-warnings

I've searched and searched and am having trouble compiling one of the Jack Audio iPhone projects. I modernized the project and keep getting this when I compile. Can't figure it out.

```
Ld /Users/zacharywilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPhoneNet-bjquhpgcjgjaitgvrbiuaobtwtfy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NetJackSlave.app/NetJackSlave normal armv7
cd /Users/zacharywilliams/trunk/jackmp/macosx/iphone
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -L/Users/zacharywilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPhoneNet-bjquhpgcjgjaitgvrbiuaobtwtfy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/zacharywilliams/trunk/jackmp/macosx/iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/zacharywilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPhoneNet-bjquhpgcjgjaitgvrbiuaobtwtfy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/zacharywilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPhoneNet-bjquhpgcjgjaitgvrbiuaobtwtfy/Build/Intermediates/iPhoneNet.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPhoneNetSlave.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NetJackSlave.LinkFileList -dead_strip libcelt.a -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -o /Users/zacharywilliams/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPhoneNet-bjquhpgcjgjaitgvrbiuaobtwtfy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NetJackSlave.app/NetJackSlave

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks for any help!

Zach

Comment: You need to show the error message from the compiler, not from the build system.

Comment: I thought that's what I was showing the error from. Sorry - teaching and learning on the fly with this. Where should go/what should I do to get the correct error? (If you don't mind taking me through a few steps) Thanks.

Comment: Under "Build Results" you should see a list of warnings and errors.

Comment: Here's the build results: http://pastie.org/2572422

Comment: I've also fixed the warnings previously but still got the error regardless. I opened a fresh version to try to compile after I figured out some other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Hey, note the line in your build log:

```
Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities (No such file or directory).
```

Here is the solution: [What is "Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities (No such file or directory)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116080/what-is-couldnt-open-shared-capabilities-memory-gscapabilities-no-such-file-or)

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't look like there are duplicates. I thought the same thing, but maybe I'm missing a detail.

Comment: try to Product > Clean , then Build again .

Comment: Updated the answer, found a solution for you :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was accidentally importing a `.m` file.